# rgbdslam map storing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the output from Kinect using rgbdslam package but I don't know how to store the obtained map or register the points cloud. I want to store the obtained map..not continuous Kinect output but sets of data...how can I do it??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35967/rgbdslam-map-storing/) by [shubh991](https://answers.ros.org/users/2567/shubh991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) to build 3D maps. Details are on the rgbdslam and octomap_server wiki pages. Did you read [rdgbdslam - Usage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#Usage)?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1